# Does the variability come from repetitions or individual differences?

Tags: repeated-measures, variability

**Background**

Let's say I ran a model (partially  stochastic) 100 times, with 10 repetitions (with 10 different seeds) on 10 data random subsamplings. I measured an error metric.
I am thus able to draw 10 boxplots to visualise the difference between the 10 subsets.

To see whether one subset dominates an other one, I did a Kruskal-Wallis test. If the test is significant, I could do pairwise Mann–Whitney *U* tests (correct me if I'm wrong).

**Question**

I want to identify whether the variability in my error metric comes from the repetitions on the same subset (i.e. from the random part of my model) or comes from the difference between data subsets (i.e. from the random subsampling). Thanks to Kruskal-Wallis, I can tell if there is a significant difference between subsamplings, but how may I go further in the analysis ?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT: following Björn answer**

As explained in comments, I runned a regression model with a random effect on the sampled dataset and a random effect of the seed nested within dataset (+ a constant).

With lme4 package in R:

```
lmer(metric ~ (1 | subset) + (1 | rep:subset))
```

As expected, I got the following error:

```
Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: rep:subset)
```

The number of observations (10*10) is equal to the number of random effects (100). My model is overspecified, since I have only one measure per repetition (*as model output is deterministic with a fixed seed*). But I'm able to force lmer, with the following code:

```
lmer(metric ~ (1 | subset) + (1 | rep:subset), control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev = "ignore", check.nobs.vs.rankZ = "ignore", check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore"))
```

In this case, I get the following warning:

```
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

Again, this is indicating that the model is overfitted. The random effects may be too complex to be supported by the data ? One of the random effect is very small:

```
Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Std.Dev.
 rep:subset (Intercept) 0.6914  
 subset     (Intercept) 0.0000  
 Residual               0.7224
```

Are these results still interpretable ? Can one argue that since the variance of subset random effect is zero, that means there is no effect of random subsampling on the error metric variability ?

Thanks again !

Comment: Have you considered running a model that explicitly models this and estimate each source of variability? Something like a regression model like explaining a suitably scaled error metric through a constant (assuming all datasets about the same size), a random effect of the sampled dataset (I guess you could also assume that those that overlap more would be more correlated, but if you have a lot of data that might not vary much, so could be negligible) and a random effect of the seed nested within dataset?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That seems to be a very good idea !
My metric ranges from 0 to 1, is the scaling still important ?
I forgot to precise each i*th* repetition on a subset was done with the same seed i, but I guess it does not change your approach.

Comment: @Björn, in fact if it's the same seed i, i might use crossed random effect rather than nested one ?

Comment: I doubt the behaviour of the model for the same see used on different subsets shares any similarities. At least, it would rather surprise me for something like neural networks, RF or GBDT. Thus, why I suggested something like nested.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

I have only one measure per repetition (since it's deterministic with a fixed seed), so adding *(1 | subset : rep)* (as one can specified in lme4 in R) is likely to cause an error, right ?

Comment: Re: transformation, modelling numbers between 0 and 1 via linear regression is not so ideal, plus variation would be higher in middle vs. edges etc., so probably best to model this as a binomial outcome (y correct out of N), which logistic regression software should let you do easily. Re: what's possible, I think it should be possible to have a nested random effect of subset, as well as for repetition within subset, I'm not 100% sure what that lme4 syntax does, so can't comment on that specifically.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.

Concerning transformation, is it still a problem if I scaled my error metric ? For my specific problem, I use the AUC-ROC.

Concerning nested random effect, I thought it could be a problem when the number of observations (100) is equal to the number of random effects (100).

Comment: If you have nothing but the AUC-ROC to go by (which you could logit transform to get the scale to $(-\infty, \infty)$) and have to use a linear regression, then you may have to treat the residual error of the model as the error from random number seeds number (you might still want to allow different SDs for different subsets of the data). If you used a logistic regression, you could have the nested random effects.

Comment: Not sure how I could do a logistic regression. My model output is a probability between 0 and 1, and my error metric is AUC-ROC against the data. Is your idea to *binarize* the output ? I tried to avoid that because it's threshold dependent. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to turn AUC-ROC into a logistic regression, no, but you originally said you were looking at accuracy, in which case it would have been obviously straightforward.